# SharePoint List form (add new choice value in dropdown)

Tags: infopath

I made a custom list in SharePoint(2010) and then created an infopath form based on that list. I created a new page in my SharePoint publishing site and added an infopath webpart that looked at my list/form. Everything works great.

I have a list with a column that accepts multiple values (a "choice" type with dropdown) and wish to add new choice options thats is available on an InfoPath(2010) webpart  form.

When add a new choice value it won't be visible to the infopath webpart form. I've i don't use the infopath webpart form, it show all(incl the new adde value). The only solution that i found is to republish the infopath form.

I first need to republish the InfoPath to make it visible. Is there an other way?

Answer (score 5):

One should update template on Sharepoint server to make its changes visible/available to Sharepoint, i.e through Infopath Form Web Part.

If you want to change choices without changing the template then you should define choices outside of the template itself. So change (in Drop Down List Box Properties) the **List Box Choices** from "Enter choices manually" to "Get Choices from an external data source" having configured the "Data Source:" (Add... button). One of the easy variants is to create and use a sharepoint list **column (in another or the same sharepoint list)** for this.

[image: Drop-Down List Box Properties - Get choices from an external data source]

Fig.1. Get choices from an external data source (in Drop-Down List Box Properties). **I've used here as datasource the Title field of another (could be the same) sharepoint list called Dropdown**

Answer to comment:

You did not provide details how you created the Infopath form but most probably, if you created the form by pressing **Customize Form** button, the choices were embedded in the form template itself

[image: Drop-Down List Box Properties - Enter choices manually]

Fig.2. Enter choices manually (in Drop-Down List Box Properties).

Which are filled indirectly through embedded into Infopath template file choices.xml, Fig.2a

[image: Uneditable locked Choices data connection in Infopath template auto-generated from sharepoint list column of type choice]

Fig.2a. Uneditable locked Choices data connection in Infopath template auto-generated from sharepoint list column of type choice

That this file choices.xml is embedded in template one can make sure by exporting source files (in Infpath Designer 2010, File > Publish > Export Source Files)

And to enable choices to change independently on Infopath template in order to avoid template republishing for updating (without Infopath template changes through updating embedded choices.xml), you can get/link choices from(to) an external data source. There are variants, but the most quick and simple one is to create and use another sharepoint list for this (cf. Fig.1)

**Update 2:**
After changing data source of drop-down list box,  make sure to delete old manual defaults in Infoapth template. In Infopath Designer 2010, **Data** tab > **Default Values** button with green checkmark (in **Sharepoint Form Data** section on ribbon)

[image: Delete remaining embedded defaults]

Fig.3. Delete remaining embedded into template defaults

So, having created and filled **Title** colum in **Dropdown** sharepoint list

[image: Fig.4. Field Title of Dropdown Sharepoint list]

Fig.4. Field Title of Dropdown Sharepoint list

linked as data source of choices in drop-down list box **Choicesss** (with underlying data field with the same name) in Sharepoint List **Choices** the choices are:

[image: Fig.5. Choicesss drop-down list box in Infopath Sharepoint List Form for sp list Choices]

Fig.5. Choicesss drop-down list box in Infopath Sharepoint List Form for sp list Choices

or **what is the same**, here is a web part aspx page with that inserted Infopath web part

[image: Fig.6. WebPart ASPX WebPage with Inserted Infopath Form Web Part]

Fig.6. WebPart ASPX WebPage with Inserted Infopath Form Web Part

[image: Fig.7. Infopath Form Web Part Properties]

Fig.7. Infopath Form Web Part Properties

[image: Fig.8. IP Web Part ASPX WebPage after Dropdown sharepoint list update]

Fig.8. IP Web Part ASPX WebPage after Dropdown sharepoint list update (without Infopath form template republishing)

[image: Fig.9. Updated Sharepoint list Dropdown]

Fig.9. Updated Sharepoint list Dropdown

**Reply to comment:**

> I think it is the default data connection 'Choices Data Connection'
>
> [image: Link photo 1]
>   Fig.10. "Link photo 1" from comment
>
> [image: "Link photo 2" from comment]
>   Fig 11. "Link photo 2" from comment
>
> By default it get's hes choices from choices.xml – mchello

I do not know how you get to situation on Fig.12 since I observe it as in my Fig.2 and what is the sense of it.
But the point is that in both mine and your situation there is embedded into Infopath template file choices.xml and in order to avoid the necessity to update choices of drop-down list box by template republishing, I proposed a workaround of  of having data source directly from a sharepoint list column of type "Single line of text"

Have I answered your question how to add/update drop-down list box choices in Infopath template (which is the same as in a webpage with  Infopath Form Web Part from it) without necessity to republish the template?

Comment: Hi Gannady, Thanks for you reply. I made a custom list in SharePoint2010(with SharePoint Designer) and then created an infopath form based on that list. When adding a new value in SharePoint Choice column it won't automatically update the form in the 'InfoPath Webpart Form'.           

When i open the form without using the 'InfoPath Webpart Form' the new added value is visible.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: By default SharePoint makes a 'Choices Data Connection' in InfoPath that is connected to the SharePoint columns. But im not able to make it visible true an 'InfoPath Webpart Form'.

Comment: After you have changed the data source for choices to another data connection/source (e.g. linked to sharepoint list), you should publish ONCE template to update that change in sharepoint. After that the choice changes will be caught from another sharepoint list without further template publishing (no tamplate changes will happen after changes in of "choices" sharepoint list)

Comment: Now try to add the 'InfoPath Webpart form' on you page, and add an new value in your SharePoint column. You will see that is won't update.

Comment: +1 for good explain.

Comment: Where you able to a new value in your 'Choicesss' colum using the SharePoint list settings?

Comment: It is in a column Title (can be different) of a sharepoint list (which I called Dropdown, Fig.4) used as datasource for dropdown list box as per Fig.1 ( though I called Data Source there as "Dropdown (Sharepoint List for Dropdown ListBox choces)"). Choices should be stored outside of template in order to avoid template's republishing with their changes. The sharepoint list for which I created Infopath form template is called Choices (Fig.5). Probably, I should have more distinct names to avoid terms overloading

Comment: I think it is the default data connection 'Choices Data Connection' [Link photo 1](http://i.imgur.com/jBCo2.png) --

[Link photo 2](http://i.imgur.com/YLElm.png) 

By default it get's hes choices from choices.xml

Comment: Choices.xml is embedded into XSN Infopath template which stipulates that in order to update Drop-Down List box choices in entities generated from it (like XML data forms, Infopath Form WebPart ASPX webpages, etc.) one should republish IP template (and sometimes relink entities based on it). I believe I answered how to update DDL choices without changing (and, so republishing) IP template?